# JAXB and STAX, getting null when element in tree has attribute

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, stax

I have a problem with unmarshaling xml. When I unmarshal an XML that hasn't got any attributes it works just fine but when I try to unmarshal an XML that has an attribute in any element I get only null values.

Here is my code:

```
<Document xmlns="sd">
<CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
    <GrpHdr>
        <NbOfTxs>2</NbOfTxs>
        <CtrlSum>100</CtrlSum>
        <blabla>bla</blabla>
    </GrpHdr>
    <PmtInf>
        <NbOfTxs>2</NbOfTxs>
        <CtrlSum>100</CtrlSum>
        <blabla>bla</blabla>
    </PmtInf>
</CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

The xml schema:

```
package XMLElement;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement(name = "GrpHdr")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class GrpHdr {   

@XmlElement(name = "MsgId")
private String msgId;
@XmlElement(name = "CreDtTm")
private String creDtTm;
@XmlElement(name = "NbOfTxs")
private String nbOfTxs;
@XmlElement(name = "CtrlSum")
private String ctrlSum;
@XmlElement(name = "InitgPty")
private String initgPty;

// MsgId
public String getMsgId() {
    return msgId;
}

public void setMsgId(String string_msgId) {
    msgId = string_msgId;
}


// CreDtTm
public String getCreDtTm() {
    return creDtTm;
}

public void setCreDtTm(String string_creDtTm) {
    creDtTm = string_creDtTm;
}


// NbOfTxs
public String getNbOfTxs() {
    return nbOfTxs;
}

public void setNbOfTxs(String string_nbOfTxs) {
    nbOfTxs = string_nbOfTxs;
}


// CtrlSum
public String getCtrlSum() {
    return ctrlSum;
}

public void setCtrlSum(String string_ctrlSum) {
    ctrlSum = string_ctrlSum;
}


// InitgPty
public String getInitgPty() {
    return initgPty;
}

public void setInitgPty(String string_initgPty) {
    initgPty = string_initgPty;
}




}
```

And the Main.java

```
package application;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import XMLElement.CstmrCdtTrfInitn;
import XMLElement.Document;
import XMLElement.GrpHdr;
import XMLElement.PmtInf;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {               

        XMLInputFactory xif2 = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        StreamSource xml2 = new StreamSource("D:\\test2.xml");
        XMLStreamReader xsr2 = xif2.createXMLStreamReader(xml2);
        xsr2.nextTag();
        while(xsr2.hasNext()) {
            if(xsr2.isStartElement() && 
xsr2.getLocalName().equals("GrpHdr")) {
                break;
            }
            xsr2.next();
        }

        JAXBContext jc2 = JAXBContext.newInstance(GrpHdr.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller2 = jc2.createUnmarshaller();
        JAXBElement<GrpHdr> jb2 = unmarshaller2.unmarshal(xsr2, 
 GrpHdr.class);
        xsr2.close();


        GrpHdr grpHdr = jb2.getValue();
        System.out.println(grpHdr.getNbOfTxs());
        System.out.println(grpHdr.getCtrlSum());

        }
}
```

When I remove the `xmlns="sd"` i get the result without any problem, but otherwise I get only null. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The `xmlns="sd"` declaration you see is not an attribute; it is a [namespace declaration](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#ns-decl). All your elements in the documents are bound to the "sd" namespace by default, but your code will match only elements with no namespace (or namespace ""). You can search JAXB and namespace handling to know how to use `namespace` parameter on the `@XmlElement` notations.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `xmlns` stands for XML Namespace. So, if you have namespace in your XML document it will going to bind all tags of XML document with that namespace, so, it's obvious that XML *unmarshalling* won't work because your tag would be say `sd:XYZ` and JAXB would be checking for `XYZ` only.

You have to declare namespace in your XML mapping class as well to make this work with namespace (or remove namespace if you don't need it). You can add [`XmlSchema`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.html) annotation in your *document* class to make it work with `xmlns` attribute.

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://www.example.com/namespaceURI",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    xmlns = {
        @XmlNs(prefix="sd", namespaceURI="http://www.example.com/namespaceURI")
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since I'm doing this first time I didn't really understand what you meant I have to do, but your info was still helpful. I have added namespace = "sd" to my xmlrootelement so it looked like this @XmlRootElement(name = "GrpHdr", namespace = "sd") and then I added the namespace also on my xml elements so they looked like this @XmlElement(name = "MsgId", namespace = "sd") and it solved my problem, but still thanks!